# How to create an email mailing list

Tags: html, css, email, forms, list

Im creating a coming soon page for a website im developing, and im adding an option for the user to enter their email address so we can email them when the site is up.
How do I do this?

Comment: Is it enought to have a textfile with the emails on the server? Are you able to use PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make a form you will need to use an HTML form to allow the user to input their email address, and then a server side technology such as php or asp.net to grab the data and either send an email directly after the form is submitted, or store in a database or text file for later processing.

You can create a simple email form by following the steps [here](http://www.ipowerweb.com/iboost/build/programming/html/862.htm).

Heres a solution for [asp.net](http://aspnet101.com/aspnet101/tutorials.aspx?id=14).

And heres one for [php](http://php.about.com/od/phpapplications/ss/form_mail.htm).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is the first link: https://web.archive.org/web/20070527112702/http://www.ipowerweb.com/iboost/build/programming/html/862.htm

Answer (score 3):

[Prefinery](http://www.prefinery.com/) will help you manage the entire "beta" process.  If you are just looking for a simple for tool, look at [emailmeform](http://www.emailmeform.com/).

If you have programming experience, you could create a database and store the email address.